# There is no sudo, yum, and other command to install inside bin folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, path, centos, cpanel

I have been trying to run my AWS EC2 as admin by using sudo but I'm unable to do so, It says ***bash- sudo command not found***. and when I try to install sudo none of other commands are working. After checking I came to know all of those files like apt-get, sudo, yum are missing from my **PATH /bin** folder. How can I get those back or how can I install them again. I'm using AWS EC2 and Centos with cPanel on it.

Comment: sudo is traditionally in `/usr/bin`, not `/bin`.  If the machine is so broken as to not have a working copy of sudo on it, you can just terminate it and bring up a new one.

Comment: @AnonCoward There are few important websites to terminate the instance, and I'm talking about `/usr/bin` there's no `sudo` and `yum` package present. Can you please suggest me how can I recover those or rescue websites safely?

Comment: Not really.  If sudo and yum are missing, then likely other important system files are missing.  One option is to stop (not terminate) the instance, create a snapshot of the volume, and mount a copy of that volume on a new machine to access the data.